# How to fix " error: failed linking references" i got this error after updating firebase dependencies needed for Admob

Tags: android, admob

error: failed linking references.

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
```

I want to add admob when added "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'" error in sync said firebase dependencies should be hire and after updating there is this error

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to fix it is to install open the project in android studio. On the opening screen you can import the project from another IDE if you are using one. Once the project is loaded, in the top menu bar there is a refactor tab. Select the "Migrate to AndroidX" option and that will do most of the work. Remember to add these lines into your gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Got same error when i added "android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true"  this does not syc and throw same error

Comment: Try to sync the gradle files with the sync gradle button